# aggregate groups results in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, aggregate

I am just wondering how can I aggregate all the results in grouped by pandas data frame.

```
data1 = {'id':['1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'],  
        'Age':[27, 24, 22, 32, 33, 36, 27, 32],    
        'Qualification':['Msc', 'MA', 'MCA', 'Phd','B.Tech', 'B.com', 'Msc', 'MA']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data1) 


grp = df.groupby('id') 
for name, group in grp:
    x = group.Age * 2 
    print (x)

0    54
1    48
Name: Age, dtype: int64
2    44
3    64
4    66
Name: Age, dtype: int64
5    72
6    54
7    64
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

I have tired like this it save only last group.

```
result = pd.DataFrame(x) 
result

Age
5   72
6   54
7   64
```

how to save all these result in pandas dataframe ?

Expected results

```
Age 
0   54
1   48
2   44
3   64
4   66
5   72
6   54
7   64
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the question?

Comment: @Nabin I hope its much clear now.

Comment: Why not `df['Age'].values * 2 `?

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon nope also, i just want to save the x  in pandas how to do that ?

Comment: df['doubled_age'] = df['Age'].map(lambda x: x*2) # Now see the value of df

Comment: @Nabin, I have large function, i need to convert the array to data frame.

Comment: @HaniIhlayyle if you are multiplying every age by 2, what is the point of grouping it? as @ComplicatedPhenomenon pointed out just do `df['Age']*2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data1 = {'id':['1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'],  
         'Age':[27, 24, 22, 32, 33, 36, 27, 32],    
         'Qualification':['Msc', 'MA', 'MCA', 'Phd','B.Tech', 'B.com', 'Msc', 'MA']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data1) 

grp = df.groupby('id') 
x = []    # Create an empty list

for name, group in grp:
   b = group.Age * 2  # Do your group vise operations 
   x.extend(b)               # Extend your list with with your restuls

result = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['Age'])
print(result)


    Age
0   54
1   48
2   44
3   64
4   66
5   72
6   54
7   64
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that will not work with me. I need to use the for loop for every group. Look again to the question, How can i conver (x) in one column in pandas

Comment: @HaniIhlayyle Did you try and then respond?

Comment: @Nabin   This solution is working. but in my case i need to do some operation for every group. The results that i have is similar to x. I have convert that to array but it dose not work for me. How save x in pandas dataframe.

Comment: @HaniIhlayyle Could have a look now?, I added a list to collect your every operation result in GroupWise.

Comment: @AshanPriyadarshana. Good stuff, Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform`:

```
df['answer'] = df.groupby('id')['Age'].transform(lambda x: x * 2)
```

output df:

```
    id  Age Qualification   answer
0   1   27  Msc             54
1   1   24  MA              48
2   2   22  MCA             44
3   2   32  Phd             64
4   2   33  B.Tech          66
5   3   36  B.com           72
6   3   27  Msc             54
7   3   32  MA              64
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
pd.DataFrame(df['Age']*2)
```

**Output**

```
    Age
0   54
1   48
2   44
3   64
4   66
5   72
6   54
7   64
```